# How to run cvlc closing after the play

Tags: vlc

Is there any parameter to run cvlc from a terminal command line in a way that the dummy interface returns control after an mp3 file is played?

Currently I run this: `me@ubuntu:~/Documents$ cvlc 732533130.mp3` and I can't type again after the file has been played, to take control I have to type ^C.

Running on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Precise Pangolin).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two ways you can instruct VLC to quit playback after the playlist is played fully:

1. By supplying the `--play-and-exit` CLI option, e.g.:

   ```
   cvlc --play-and-exit audio1.mp3 audio2.mp3
   ```

   or

   ```
   vlc --play-and-exit audio1.mp3 audio2.mp3
   ```

   or creating a bash alias (in ~/.bashrc):

   ```
   alias cvlc='cvlc --play-and-exit'
   ```
2. By adding the dummy item `vlc://quit` to your playlist, e.g.:

   ```
   cvlc audio1.mp3 audio2.mp3 vlc://quit
   ```

   or

   ```
   vlc audio1.mp3 audio2.mp3 vlc://quit
   ```

---

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10249261/1708932

Comment: This just worked out.  thx

Comment: 1st does not seem to work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

you can always take control by suffixing an `&` at the end of the command. the command will launch and you will also have control on the terminal.

try

`cvlc 732533130.mp3 &`

Comment: Sure, but then the process does not stop, how to kill it? (not manually, I mean).

Comment: whenever you end a command with `&`, there is a process id (`<pid>`) visible on the terminal in the immediate following line. you can kill the process by typing in `kill <pid>`

Comment: The thing is that I have to play a bulk of mp3 files from an octave script, and killing them all manually afterwards will be tough.  Any other solution?

Comment: i am sorry, i dont have an answer for this case , but someone else would have one. Please ask a new question and mention your exact issue. and meanwhile if my answer helped, you can mark it as an answer.